# load module via /etc/modules

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

I want to load my kernel module `hello.ko` on boot in Ubuntu 12.04. I placed it in `/lib/modules/3.8.0-31-generic/kernel/ubuntu/hello.ko`, ran `depmod -a`, and added "hello" to `/etc/modules`.

However, when I restart, there is no "hello" module in `lsmod`. In `/var/log/upstart/module-init-tools.log` there is a string "FATAL: Module hello not found."

If I run `modprobe hello` everything is fine. What's wrong with `/etc/modules`? Where is it trying to find modules?

Answer (score -1):

Run `sudo update-initramfs -u` to get your module in the initial ramdisk for the current kernel. Otherwise it will not load on init.

Comment: This is not necessary. Modules listed in `/etc/modules` are loaded on init (from the `kmod` job, which runs once udev is up).

Comment: @Gilles It is necessary. If the module does not exist in the initrd, then init can obviously not load it when it has not yet mounted any filesystems.

Comment: You're confusing the `/init` script in the initramfs and the init system which is Upstart. The initramfs doesn't even contain `/etc/modules`, that's part of the root filesystem. There's an Upstart job (`kmod`) that loads modules listed in `/etc/modules`. This happens after the root filesystem is mounted, it has nothing to do with the initramfs.

Comment: Can you doublecheck if the running kernel is the correct version with the path you placed the module with `uname -r`. Please also check the output of `modinfo /lib/modules/3.8.0-31-generic/kernel/ubuntu/hello.ko`.

Comment: @Gilles You were right, kmod loads the module after the rootfs is mounted. Since `/etc/modprobe.d/` did end up in the initramfs I supposed that it would also be the case for `/etc/modules` which is apparently not true.